# Shared preferences not working correctly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store some strings in a shared preference file and then retrieve them in another activity, except it doesn't seem to be working. Any guidance as to where im going wrong would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

```
public void save(View view) {
    SavePreferences("name", nameS);
    SavePreferences("current", currentS);
    SavePreferences("goal", goalS);
    SavePreferences("CurrentBmi", cBmiS);
    SavePreferences("goalBmi", gBmiS);
    Toast.makeText(this, "profile Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

}

private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}






 public class Progress extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String test = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "");
    String test2 = sharedPreferences.getString("current", "");
    TextView testy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    testy.setText(test);
    TextView testz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test2);
    testz.setText(test2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the code you have you are limiting the access of sharedpreferences to activity(context) level.

Values saved in activity Activity `MainActivity` will not be available in activity `Progress` since you are using `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);`

Change this to

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

or

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

getPreferences:

```
public SharedPreferences getPreferences (int mode)
```

Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are **private to this activity**.

Comment: The first bit makes perfect sense, thanks. Not sure what you're getting at with the getPreferences though. After changing the saving, will my method of retrieval not work?

Comment: I just posted the definition of getPreferences from the docs which says it retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are private to this activity.